# Does iOS display some kind of reminder when an auto-renewable subscription is due to renew or expire without renewal?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I've not seen anything to suggest it does but it's a customer requirement, so I guess we'll have to had roll it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not, and there's no way on the device to tell if the subscription will expire at next renewal date (i.e. if the user has cancelled the subscription).

You can pass the last receipt to your server which can then verify the receipt. Then Apple will tell you if the subscription has expired.

Comment: Hey matt, thanks for the answer. Yeah, discovered meanwhile that Apple send an email to tell the user subscription is about to expire. Since we've already got the receipt data on the server we'll check it there and either send a push notification (most user friendly, I think) or set a flag in the shop-content data (requested and parsed by the app on startup) to remind the user.